# Changing quantity in sql database, based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, database-connection

I have to following script to run a treeview script, to display information contained in a my database:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os

root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.title("Inventory Balance")
conn = sqlite3.connect('MyStock.sql3')


def db():
    global conn, mycursor
    mycursor = conn.cursor()


def data():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MyStock")  # Set mycursor as row to execute in. Read database
    for row in mycursor:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=row[0:6])
    conn.close()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Arial", 14), foreground="yellow", background="black")

tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), height=30, show="headings")
tree.pack(side='left')

tree.heading(0, text="Item Code")
tree.heading(1, text="Description")
tree.heading(2, text="Category")
tree.heading(3, text="Unit")
tree.heading(4, text="Quantity")

tree.column(0, width=300)
tree.column(1, width=300)
tree.column(2, width=300)
tree.column(3, width=150)
tree.column(4, width=150)

# Inserting Scrollbar
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

# Configuring style
style = Style()
style.configure('W.TButton', font=('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'), foreground='red')

# Program to open with Button1


def userform1():
    os.system('python UserForm_Test_altered_.py')

# Inserting Buttons
''' Button 1'''
btn1 = Button(root, text='Exit', style='W.TButton', command=root.destroy)
btn1.pack(side='right')

''' Button 2'''
btn2 = Button(root, text='Issue / Receive', command=userform1)
btn2.pack(side='left')

db()
data()
root.mainloop()
```

From the submit button I open a GUI like this:[Userform_Test_altered_.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cspYg.jpg)

With Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry('380x400')
# root.state('zoomed')
root.title("Received")
style = Style()

ItemCode = StringVar()
Description = StringVar()
Quantity = IntVar()
Unit = StringVar()
var = IntVar()
c = StringVar()
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()


def database():
    code = ItemCode.get()

    # desc = Description.get()

    quantity = Quantity.get()

    # unit = Unit.get()

    # dep = c.get()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('MyStock.sql3')

    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        # sql = 'UPDATE MyStock SET Quantity=?, Category=?, Unit=?, Description=? WHERE ItemCode=?'
        # cursor.execute(sql, (quantity, dep, unit, desc, code))
        cursor.execute('UPDATE MyStock SET Quantity=? WHERE ItemCode=?', (quantity, code,))
        cursor.close()
        conn.commit()


def data2():
    os.system('python main_screen.py')

# Inserting labels and field of input
label_0 = Label(root, text="Stock Movement", width=20, font=("bold", 20)).place(x=90, y=23)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Item Code", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20, y=90)

entry_1 = Entry(root, textvar=ItemCode, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=180, y=90)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Description", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20, y=140)

entry_2 = Entry(root, textvar=Description, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=180, y=140)

label_3 = Label(root, text="Category", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20,y=190)

list1 = ['', 'BINDING', 'BOWS', 'CARTONS', 'CHEMICAL']

list = OptionMenu(root, c, *list1)

list.config(width=20)

c.set('CATEGORY')

list.place(x=178, y=190)

label_4 = Label(root, text="Quantity", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20, y=290)

entry_4 = Entry(root, textvar=Quantity, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=180, y=290)

label_5 = Label(root, text="Unit", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20, y=240)

entry_5 = Entry(root, textvar=Unit, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=180, y=240)

# Style of buttons
style.configure('W.TButton', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), foreground='red')
style.configure('S.TButton', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), foreground='blue')

# Inserting buttons
submit1 = Button(root, text='Submit', style='S.TButton', width=11, command=database).place(x=20, y=340)
exit1 = Button(root, text='Exit', style='W.TButton',width=11, command=root.destroy).place(x=260, y=340)


data2()
root.mainloop()
```

I would need the quantity to be added to the quantity displayed in the database upon the closing of the userform script.
(This quantity can increase or decrease, obviously based on math principles, if you add a negative number it would subtract.)

The ideal would be for the database's connection to be continuous as long as the treeview script is running.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. My knowledge of the specific  wording and/or calculations and where to place the code is quite limited.

Thank you beforehand

Comment: If you want to change the quantity of a record in database, you should use `UPDATE` statement instead of `INSERT`.  I don't know whether sqlite supports `REPLACE` statement, if yes, it is better to use `REPLACE` as it will create new record if the record does not exist, otherwise, it will update existing record.

Comment: I think the update would be more accurate as I do not want it to replace the value, rather to adjust it. If the item does not exist, it must give an error message stating "The entry is incorrect".

Comment: @acw1668 I briefly updated the code. Is there any option to auto-fill the rest of the inputs, based on the Item Code value?

Comment: You are using `UPDATE` statement wrong.  The syntax should be `UPDATE TABLE MyStock SET field1 = value1, field2 = value2 WHERE ...`.

Comment: @acw1668 I altered the code from what I could understand from your description. I want to confirm that I would change it in the script of the tkinter that is being filled in. Thank you again.

Comment: You better learn SQL syntax first.

Comment: Since you use sqlite, refer its [document](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

Comment: @acw1668 I found a good source. Thank you for the help regardless. It makes sense that the SQL commands will all be placed inside `cursor.execute('here')` so that the SQL program reads it as such and follows that script. So, theoretically. All of the scripts in that bracket will comply with SQL language. Please correct me if this is not the case. Thank you

Comment: @acw1668 I read through a couple of documents and articles and found that SQLite does not allow the UPDATE function to be used when using a variable. So, in my case the SQLite will not be able to suffice, if this is true, because the table contents will be updated by the Quantity entry in the Userform_Test_altered.py. Please advise as I would have to change software, before compiling all of the necessary code and finding it will never work integrated with the use I need. Thank you

Comment: Try `sql = 'UPDATE MyStock SET Description=?, Category=?, Unit=?, Quantity=? WHERE ItemCode=?'`, and then `cursor.execute(sql, (name2, dep, name4, name3, name1))`.

Comment: @acw1668 I get the following error upon execution -                                                  `File "stock_receive.py", line 38, in database`
    `cursor.execute('UPDATE MyStock SET Quantity=VALUE(?)', quantity)`
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: VALUE`

Comment: Should be `cursor.execute('UPDATE MyStock SET Quantity=?', (quantity,))`.  But without `WHERE` clause, it will update all records in MyStock table.

Comment: @acw1668 Getting this now - `cursor.execute('UPDATE MyStock SET Quantity=?', (quantity))
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`

Comment: What is the type of `quantity`?

Comment: @acw1668 I read a few articles where they mention using variables in the SQLite database integrated with python, but there is a mountain of code attached to the same article and I want to end up with an installable .exe file to run on my other computers to install the software.

Comment: Should be `(quantity,)` (note the comma), not `(quantity)`.

Comment: If you have the WHERE clause, it will only update records that the WHERE clause is true.

Comment: @acw1668 I sorted out the remaining issues. I only wanted to update the quantity field. Please find the altered code above. I want to research on how to update the treeview upon any alteration. Is it possible or should I do some research and ask again? Thank you for the help and patience.

Comment: You should put the line  `conn.commit()` inside the `with` block.  In order to update the treeview, you need to clear the treeview and insert the records again.

Comment: @acw1668 So the treeview need to be refreshed with the new information. Is there no way to loop the connection, so that the treeview does not need to be run again?

Comment: Calling `data()` function will refresh the treeview.

Comment: @acw1668 I have `data()` between `db()` and `root.mainloop()` in the treeview script. Should I repeat these three items at the bottom of my `Userform_Test_altered_.py` script?

Comment: Actually, your script `UserForm_Test_altered_.py` cannot call `db()` and `data()` as they are undefined inside the script.  As you are using `os.system()` to call the script, you should modify the script to return a value whether new record is inserted.  The value can be retrieved by the result of `os.system()`.  Use that value to determine whether to call `data()` inside `userform1()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 I altered the script and retrieved the treeview script`main_screen.py` into the`Userform_Test_altered.py` The biggest issue is the re-run of the `main_screen.py` script and the addition of data, instead of replacing the data. The option of both is still negotiable based on the logic of the SQLite interpretation. Thank you

Comment: Have you ever tested your changes?  It does not work to run `main_screen.py` inside `UserForm_Test_Altered_.py` as it will create another main window, not the original main window.  As what I said in my previous comment, modify `UserForm_Test_Altered_.py` to return a value and check that value in `main_screen.py` to determine whether to reload the data into treeview.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify `UserForm_Test_Altered_.py` to return value whether record has been updated:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os
import sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry('380x400')
# root.state('zoomed')
root.title("Received")

ItemCode = StringVar()
Description = StringVar()
Quantity = IntVar()
Unit = StringVar()
var = IntVar()
c = StringVar()
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()


def database():
    code = ItemCode.get()
    quantity = Quantity.get()

    with sqlite3.connect('MyStock.sql3') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('UPDATE MyStock SET Quantity=? WHERE ItemCode=?', (quantity, code,))
        updated = cursor.rowcount
        cursor.close()
        conn.commit()
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit(updated) # return value whether record has been updated


# Inserting labels and field of input
Label(root, text="Stock Movement", width=20, font=("bold", 20)).place(x=90, y=23)

Label(root, text="Item Code", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20, y=90)
Entry(root, textvar=ItemCode, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=180, y=90)

Label(root, text="Description", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20, y=140)
Entry(root, textvar=Description, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=180, y=140)

Label(root, text="Category", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20,y=190)
list1 = ['', 'BINDING', 'BOWS', 'CARTONS', 'CHEMICAL']
list = OptionMenu(root, c, *list1)
list.config(width=20)
c.set('CATEGORY')
list.place(x=178, y=190)

Label(root, text="Quantity", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20, y=290)
Entry(root, textvar=Quantity, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=180, y=290)

Label(root, text="Unit", width=20, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=20, y=240)
Entry(root, textvar=Unit, font=("bold", 11)).place(x=180, y=240)

# Style of buttons
style = Style()
style.configure('W.TButton', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), foreground='red')
style.configure('S.TButton', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), foreground='blue')

# Inserting buttons
Button(root, text='Submit', style='S.TButton', width=11, command=database).place(x=20, y=340)
Button(root, text='Exit', style='W.TButton',width=11, command=root.destroy).place(x=260, y=340)

root.mainloop()
```

Then in `main_screen.py` check the return value of `os.system(...)` to determine whether to reload the data into treeview:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os

root = Tk()
#root.state('zoomed')
root.title("Inventory Balance")

def load_data():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    with sqlite3.connect('MyStock.sql3') as conn:
        mycursor = conn.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MyStock")
        for row in mycursor:
            tree.insert('', 'end', values=row[0:6])

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Arial", 14), foreground="yellow", background="black")

tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), height=30, show="headings")
tree.pack(side='left')

tree.heading(0, text="Item Code")
tree.heading(1, text="Description")
tree.heading(2, text="Category")
tree.heading(3, text="Unit")
tree.heading(4, text="Quantity")

tree.column(0, width=300)
tree.column(1, width=300)
tree.column(2, width=300)
tree.column(3, width=150)
tree.column(4, width=150)

# Inserting Scrollbar
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

# Configuring style
style = Style()
style.configure('W.TButton', font=('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'), foreground='red')

# Program to open with Button1

def userform1():
    ret = os.system('python UserForm_Test_altered_.py')
    if ret:
        # record updated, reload data
        load_data()

# Inserting Buttons
''' Button 1'''
btn1 = Button(root, text='Exit', style='W.TButton', command=root.destroy)
btn1.pack(side='right')

''' Button 2'''
btn2 = Button(root, text='Issue / Receive', command=userform1)
btn2.pack(side='left')

load_data()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I run the script after any and all changes to see if the result is satisfactory, hence the quick replies. I would like to thank you for all of the effort. The re-post of the correct code worked absolutely amazing. I am adapting the `Userform_Test_altered_.py` to have more complicated integration. Hopefully all is going to work. The foundation is correct. Thank  you again.